# How to detect string truncation

Tags: sap-ase, jtds

I use jTDS 1.2.6 to connect Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7.0.
When a prepared statement insert rows in a table with a `VARCHAR(16)` column, the strings are silently truncated.
The insertion is successful, no warning and no `DataTruncation` exception is raised whereas the encoded is string is truncated to 16 octet.

How could I detect the string truncation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive Server truncates entries to the specified column length without warning or error, unless you set `string_rtruncation on`. See the Reference Manual: Commands.

MSSQL always detect truncation of strings and the option STRING_RTRUNCATION  does not exist. Here is an excerpt of jTDS SAfeTest.testDataTruncException()

```
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
if (!con.getMetaData().getDatabaseProductName().toLowerCase().startsWith("microsoft")) {
    // By default Sybase will silently truncate strings,
    // set an option to ensure that an exception is thrown.
     stmt.execute("SET STRING_RTRUNCATION ON");
}
```